# Moving SQL server 2016 DB's from mirroring to HA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, mirroring, high-availability

We have Windows Server 2016 machines with SQL server 2016 standard edition. Currently mirroring is implemented and now are planning to move to HA with 1 listener for each DB. We have multiple DB's

In few DB stored procedure we have call to other DB with hardcode name.

Once we move to HA with 1 listener for each DB, will this new configuration be any issue for me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on standard edition - you will be using [Basic Always On availability groups for a single database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017).

> Once we move to HA with 1 listener for each DB, will this new configuration be any issue for me?

The only issue that I see is that you have to failover all the interrelated databases together (since your app has cross db calls e.g. joins, etc).

I don't see any other issues except the [limitations highlighted here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017#limitations).

Comment: The requirements for support in distributed transactions is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/transactions-always-on-availability-and-database-mirroring?view=sql-server-2017